# Using data from multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, database, syntax

Here's my issue: I have 3 tables, with overlapping information (specifically, the username) in each. Except the username row isn't named the same thing in every table. Because the username is specific to the user, it makes sense to get all the other information about the user based on the username. Here's what I have. (The first function returns the query, the second function returns the information in an array (or is supposed to, anyway).

```
function get_user_by_id($id) {
    global $connection;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM ownerOrganization, owner, queue_acl";
    $query .=" WHERE owner.ownerId=ownerOrganization.ownerId";
    $query .=" AND owner.ownerId=queue_acl.user_id";
    $query .= " AND owner.ownerId ='{$id}'";
    $result_set = mysql_query($query);
    confirm_query($result_set);
    if ($user = mysql_fetch_array($result_set)) {
        return $user;
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
}

function get_user_id() {
    if (isset($_GET['ownerId'])) {
        return get_user_by_id($_GET['ownerId']); 
    } 
}
```

But when I do something like, `$sel_user = get_user_id();` on another page, it doesn't actually pull up any of the selected users information... I assume that this is happening because my syntax regarding working with multiple tables is incorrect. Anyway, any input would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please post sample data and desired output.

Comment: is the `ownerId` / `user_id` a unique key in these tables? Does each of these tables have data for each user?

Comment: suggest you read up on how to use JOIN.

Comment: You sure that `on another page` there is `ownerId` in the GET parameters???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use JOINS, take this snipcode in example :

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM (ownerOrganization INNER JOIN owner ON owner.ownerId=ownerOrganization.ownerId) INNER JOIN queue_acl ON owner.ownerId=queue_acl.user_id";
$query .=" WHERE owner.ownerId ='{$id}'";
```

Regards

Comment: Using of `inner join` will lead to no result for a row where there is no data in joined table... Sure he wants this?

Comment: That's *just* the equivalence of his first query. As we do not know where the "prior" data are, we cannot define if it is a LEFT or a RIGHT join. And I use to think that FULL JOIN are too costly...

Answer (score 0):

I was typing what more or less what @MTranchant wrote.  I would suggest renaming your columns for easier query authoring and to avoid confusion.  For instance your ownerOrganization.ownerid could be named oo_ownerid, and the other columns in the table could follow that naming convention.

Also, have you run the query against the database with a hard-coded $id that you know exists?

Lastly in the query string being sent  to the next page, does a ownerId parameter appear that looks like "&ownerId="?